# setInterval after setTimeout is executed constantly

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I'v got code that checks current position of right top corner of some element:

```
function checkContentPos(e) {
    var positionLeft = 0,
    checkTabPos = null,
    pos;

    e = $(e).filter('li');
    alert($(e).attr('class'));
    //alert($(e).attr('class'));
    checkTabPos = setInterval(
        function () {
            ii++;
            debug(ii);
            pos = $(e).offset(); 
            pos['left'] += parseInt($(e).css('width'));
            positionLeft = pos.left;
            debug(positionLeft);
        }, 40);
    function stopCheckTabPos() {
        debug('stopCheckTabPos invoked')
        clearInterval('checkTabPos');
    }
    setTimeout(stopCheckTabPos, 400);
    return(positionLeft);
    };
```

But I looks like its looped to instanity. After setTimeout it's still constantly invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 clearInterval('checkTabPos');
```

Don't use quotes here. How would that even work? You need to pass in the identifier returned by `setInterval`, not some arbitrary string.

Comment: It was so easy... It took me hour's. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval) with the string `'checkTabPos'` when you should be using it with the variable

```
function stopCheckTabPos() {
    debug('stopCheckTabPos invoked')
    clearInterval(checkTabPos);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, and maybe someone can tell my why I cannout access the positionLeft variable? It's still zero after execution of setInterval, but when it's in the function the value is correct.

Comment: The `return` at the end of `checkContentPos` happens before the executions, not after and hence `positionLeft` is `0`. `setInterval` and `setTimeout` don't block execution. You'd need to have some callback function invoked by `stopCheckTabPos` after clearing the interval.